# Can complementisers be glossed as "C"

Tags: interlinear-gloss, complement

I have been glossing complementisers as "C" for years and I could have sworn that I got this from the [Leipzig Glossing Rules](https://www.eva.mpg.de/lingua/pdf/Glossing-Rules.pdf) list of standard abbreviations, however, recently, when I looked, I saw that "complementizer" is given as "COMP".

In the [Wikipedia article "List of glossing abbreviations"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_glossing_abbreviations), only "COMP", "CMP", "COMPL", "COMPLR" and "SUBR" (subordinator) are currently listed for "complementizer". There is "C-" for "complementizing (prefix on case abbreviation)", which, I'm presuming is used like CNOM for "complementising nominative", but C on its own only seems to be listed for "common gender", "current evidence" and "conceptualizer".

When I go back to a [version of the page from 9th September 2013](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_glossing_abbreviations&oldid=572133643), I see "C" listed for "common noun" and "complementizer", but at some point that has been undone. There is no citation listed for it there, but I have a memory (which may of course not be real) of seeing that also in the Leipzig glossing rules. When I learnt the word complementiser, I learnt it with the glossing abbreviation "C".

Now, it seems to me that C is only used as the standard abbreviation of complementisers in generative grammar, but not (or no longer) in glossing. According to the Leipzig glossing rules as I see them today, C is not given as a standard abbreviation of anything. I can't find any evidence of what I have used as common practice for years, other than an old, unsourced Wikipedia edit.

Of course, I know I can use non-standard abbreviations and define them in a glossary, but I find it frustrating that the standard abbreviation is now apparently "COMP", which I have always used for "comparative".

I'm just curious if anyone knows if it was in fact changed in the Leipzig glossing rules (and why!) or if there is widespread use of "C" for complementisers in glossing (not just in generative grammar) that could justify readding "C" to the list of glossing abbreviations on Wikipedia.